# Testflight complains about developer certificate being used to sign the app

Tags: ios, certificate, provisioning-profile, testflight

Suddenly I started getting this from Testflight when uploading a new build of an app:

> This build is signed with a Developer certificate, it can only be installed by devices with the Developer feature enabled. We recommend signing with a distribution provisioning profile for best results.

And my users have problems installing the app. I've gone over the project settings again and again, but everything looks right.

I've set the team provisioning profile to be the provisioning profile for both debug and release, I've even changed to a different team, but still the same problem.

Am I looking in the wrong place here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just came across this exact same issue. It looks like TestFlight have added a new check and are flagging developer provisioning profiles when they didn't in the past. Take a read of this (posted yesterday):

[Testflight article](http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/1415172-%22developer-certificate-detected%22-what-do-i-do-)

I've just uploaded a build to test flight using my normal approach to signing (with a developer certificate), ignored the testflight message, and distributed to my test users. Seemed to work OK.

Comment: I was doing the same thing (signing with developer and ignoring the effort) until yesterday, currently; signing with developer account works only on devices that have been connected to Xcode - Maybe this is my solo problem - I'll post another comment/answer when I'm able to fix my problem - as even the AdHoc signing doesn't work for me at the moment.

Comment: Me again - I was finally able to solve my annoying problem and it turned out not to be related to development/adhoc builds - both works as usual when you ignore the error, my problem was with a package named SenTestingKit.framework - that works fine if you're running on a device that has been connected to Xcode before - I've changed that package to optional and YAY - my 24 continuos struggle has paid off - Thanks for the answer though +1